# Docker Quickstart Terminal crash on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker, iterm

I'm using MacOS X Yosemite 10.10.5. Recently, I installed Docker Toolbox. However, the iTerm crashed right after I open Docker Quickstart Toolbox.

```
iTerm got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.
iTerm got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)
```

[image]

Does anyone help me fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: old version os apple script? Can you upgrade it first ? refer https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/32363-archived-502-applescript-bug/

Comment: You might want to report this on the Docker Toolbox GitHub repo: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues